# Перемещение элементов js

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Как реализовать перемещение блоков между собой так, чтобы элементы не "ломались" из-за того, что все элементы внутри блока так же переносятся.
[image: Блоки ломаются вот так]

```js
const main = document.querySelector(".item_list");

main.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((e) => {
  e.ondragstart = (e) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("id", e.target.id);
  };
  e.ondragover = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  e.ondrop = (e) => {
    let v = e.target.innerHTML;
    let fromEl = document.querySelector("#" + e.dataTransfer.getData("id"));
    e.target.innerHTML = fromEl.innerHTML;
    fromEl.innerHTML = v;
  };
});
```

```css
.row {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #fff1eb;
}

.item_list {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #fffbeb;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff1eb;
}

.item__name {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.item__description {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="row">
      <div class="menu"></div>
      <div class="item_list">
        <div id="c1" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c2" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка2</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка22
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c3" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка3</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка23
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c4" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка4</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка24
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c5" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка5</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка5
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c6" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка6</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка6
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c7" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка7</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка7
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c8" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка8</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка8
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c9" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка9</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка9
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c10" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка10</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка10
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c11" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка11</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка11
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c12" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка12</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка12
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.target` — Элемент, на который реально тыкнули (кнопка, абзац и прочее, что находится внутри элемента). `e.currentTarget` — Элемент, на котором сработало событие (`".item"`). Будет работать как надо, если все `target` заменить на `currentTarget`.

А если использовать не стрелочные функции, `e.currentTarget` можно заменить на `this` (у стрелок нет this). Заодно вытащить их из цикла, чтобы на каждой итерации не создавалась новая функция, а использовалась одна и та же.

```js
// ".item_list .item" — Селектор через пробел, «Все .item внутри .item_list»
document.querySelectorAll(".item_list .item").forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("dragstart", item_dragstart);
  e.addEventListener("dragover", item_dragover);
  e.addEventListener("drop", item_drop);
});

function item_dragstart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("id", this.id);
}

function item_dragover(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function item_drop(e) {
  let from = document.querySelector("#" + e.dataTransfer.getData("id"));
  
  [this.innerHTML, from.innerHTML] = [from.innerHTML, this.innerHTML];
  // Меняет местами значения («Деструктурирующее присваивание»)
}
```

```css
.row {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #fff1eb;
}

.item_list {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #fffbeb;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff1eb;
}

.item__name {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.item__description {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="row">
      <div class="menu"></div>
      <div class="item_list">
        <div id="c1" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c2" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка2</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка22
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c3" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка3</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка23
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c4" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка4</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка24
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c5" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка5</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка5
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c6" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка6</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка6
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c7" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка7</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка7
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c8" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка8</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка8
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c9" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка9</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка9
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c10" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка10</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка10
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c11" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка11</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка11
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="c12" class="item" draggable="true">
          <span class="item__name">Коробка12</span>
          <span class="item__description">
            Какая-то коробка12
          </span>
          <button>
            Купить22
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее! Вы меня спасли!